# How do you move an animation curve in maya python?

Tags: python, animation, expression, maya, curves

If I wanted to move it correctly. I would select the whole curve and type *=.42 in the graph editor second box and the whole curve will move up. How do I do this using python. Do I use expression?

Answer (score 0):

I used this seems to work.

cmds.scaleKey("animCurve.x", valuePivot=0, valueScale=0.42 )